How to Structure an App with Core and Feature Modules and access feature modules without importing?
I'm working on a project where I need to divide my application into different modules. I want to create a core module that imports feature modules, and then have other modules use the core module to access these features. The problem is that the core module is imported in appModule but i can't use it in other modules
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MaterialModule } from 'src/app/material.module';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
@NgModule({
  imports: [TheModuleToUse],
  exports: [TheModuleToUse]
})
export class CoreModule {}

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { CourseRoutingModule } from './Course-routing.module';
import { MaterialModule } from 'src/app/TheModuleToUse';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [CourseRoutingModule.components],
  imports: [CommonModule, DeveloperRoutingModule, TheModuleToUse]
})
export class CourseModule {}

now in the developer module i shoudn't import TheModuleToUse because i already import it in core module and core module is imported in app.module.Ts

Modules are a single individual unit, you can export the data out of it, but you cannot expect the module to read the parent module contents.
So CourseModule must have its own import of CoreModule, because the import of CoreModule is not visible to CourseModule, eventhough you import it on AppModule
When you share a module between multiple other modules, the fetch happens only once, so if a module is loaded its reused, so there is no overhead of fetching the same module again and again!

Thanks ! , yes you are right when i import coreModule in child module it works ! ,  so there is no solution that i import core module that contain the material and all features only once then acces them directly without importing coremodule evreytime in the child modules ?

@ahmeed As far as I know no! since angular takes care of the imports, the same module is not fetched twice, so you do not need to worry about repeating imports!

Thanks ! so it does not affect performance ? because i'm splitting routes By module for performance improving

@ahmeed The shared module usually grows larger in size as the app grows, the solution for that is standalone component, which do not need modules, they can just be imported and used directly, so try to strike a balance between the modules and standalone component and you will be fine!
